# Using setInterval() and clearInterval() in classes

Tags: javascript, class, oop

I have a problem understanding how to use setInterval() and clearInterval() in classes. I'm trying to build a timer that starts from 0 until i decide to stop it.

Up to now i managed to have a method that when you call it, the timer starts but when i try to pause it it just ignores my method and continues.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <p id="timer">im here</p>
    </div>
    <button>Start/Stop Timer</button>
    <button>Reset Timer</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
class Timer {
  constructor(){
    this.isRunning = false;
    this.currTimer = 0;
    this.runTimer;
    var timer = document.getElementById('timer');
  }

  start(){
    this.isRunning = true;
    if (this.isRunning) {
      var currentTime = this.currTimer;
      this.runTimer = setInterval(function(){
        timer.innerHTML = ++currentTime;
      },1000)
    }
  }

  pause(){
    this.isRunning = false;
    if (this.isRunning = false) {
      clearInterval(this.runTimer)
    }
  }
}

var test = new Timer();
test.start();
test.pause();// put this after a few seconds
```

I'm also pretty sure i'm using "this" wrong.
I just learned this new stuff and trying to build it.

Comment: `if (this.isRunning = false) {` — You made a typo. That's an assignment, not a comparison.

Comment: true.. fixed it but still doesn't work

Comment: I've rolled back the edit that fixed it. Questions shouldn't be moving targets. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use it after the object is constructed, your `timer` local variable needs to be a property instead, so in the constructor, change

```
var timer = document.getElementById('timer');
```

to

```
this.timer = document.getElementById('timer');
```

Then in `start`, you need to use `this.timer` as well — and that means you want to use an *arrow function*, not a traditional function, for the `setInterval` callback so that the function closes over `this`. You probably want to use `this.currTimer` directly rather than copying it to a variable:

```
this.runTimer = setInterval(() => {
    this.timer.innerHTML = ++this.currTimer;
},1000);
```

The logic there also needs tweaking: You've just assigned `true` to `this.isRunning`, so there's no need to check it afterward. But really, you want to check it beforehand:

```
start(){
  if (!this.isRunning) {
    this.isRunning = true;
    this.runTimer = setInterval(() => {
      this.timer.innerHTML = ++this.currTimer;
    },1000);
  }
}
```

You also need to use `==` or `===`, not `=`, when doing comparisons like this one:

```
if (this.isRunning = false) { // Needs == or ===
```

But the logic in `pause` has a problem: You've just set `this.isRunning` to `false`, so checking it on the next line, it'll always be false. Instead, check it before you assign to it. Also, use just `if (flag)` or `if (!flag)` rather than using `== true` or `== false`:

```
pause(){
  if (this.isRunning) {
    clearInterval(this.runTimer)
    this.isRunning = false;
  }
}
```

Seems to work with those changes:

```js
class Timer {
    constructor() {
        this.isRunning = false;
        this.currTimer = 0;
        this.runTimer;
        this.timer = document.getElementById('timer');
    }

    start() {
        if (!this.isRunning) {
            this.isRunning = true;
            this.runTimer = setInterval(() => {
                this.timer.innerHTML = ++this.currTimer;
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

    pause() {
        if (this.isRunning) {
            clearInterval(this.runTimer);
            this.isRunning = false;
        }
    }
}

var test = new Timer();
test.start();
setTimeout(function() {
  test.pause(); // put this after a few seconds
}, 4000);
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>
```

---

I also strongly recommend using `;` consistently (such as after the call to `setInterval`). JavaScript has automatic semicolon insertion (ASI) so it will act like you included semicolons in some places even if you haven't, but you can't rely on it unless you have a **very** thorough understanding of the ASI rules.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In your condition, you're assigning instead of comparing.

This:

```
pause() {
  this.isRunning = false;
  if (this.isRunning = false) {
    clearInterval(this.runTimer)
  }
}
```

Should be:

```
pause() {
  this.isRunning = false;
  if (this.isRunning === false) {
    clearInterval(this.runTimer)
  }
}
```

Or, because the condition will always evaluate to true, just:

```
pause() {
  this.isRunning = false;

  clearInterval(this.runTimer)
}
```

Comment: It should probably `if (this.isRunning) { clearInterval(this.runTimer); this.isRunning = false; }` but that would require fixes to the rest of the code.